# Testing In iOS failed after passing first

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am doing testing in iOS app. I have following code in setUp method:

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    rest=[[Restaurant alloc]init];
    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    array=[rest getTheWebData];

}
```

I implement first test case which for array which is successful:

```
- (void)testDataArray_Should_Not_Nil
{
        STAssertNotNil(array,@"array is nil");



}
```

Soon after i have following test case for array in which implementation is same :

```
-(void)testResult_Should_Be_Valid_Category_For_Given_Node
{

    STAssertNotNil(array,@"array is nil");
}
```

this test case is failing due to null array .Why i am getting null in second case as soon as passing the first case?

Answer (score 0):

your array points to an object returned by the getTheWebData method which I supposed returns the array in autoreleased, so it's likely that your array is released after the end of the setUp method.
The alloc init you did in first place is pointless and it leaks because then you assign the array again in the next line.
The best way to do it is this:

```
array=[[rest getTheWebData] retain];
```

I'm assuming that you're not using ARC